# iOS Programatically flashlight is not powerful

Tags: ios, flash, camera

To turn on torch and flashlight I'm using this code:

```
if ([device hasTorch]) {
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    [device setTorchMode: on ? AVCaptureTorchModeOn : AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
    [device setFlashMode: on ? AVCaptureFlashModeOn : AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
    [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus];
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

But if you compare it with the native camera app you will see that the native flashlight is more powerful when capturing photo 
Is there a way to make it powerful when capturing a photo similar to native camera flash?

Answer (score 0):

you can update your code with this code:

```
- (void)setTorchToLevel:(float)torchLevel
{
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([device hasTorch]) {
        [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
        if (torchLevel <= 0.0) {
            [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
        }
        else {
            if (torchLevel >= 1.0)
                torchLevel = AVCaptureMaxAvailableTorchLevel;
            BOOL success = [device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:torchLevel   error:nil];
        }
        [device unlockForConfiguration];
    }
}
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code.

```
[device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:AVCaptureMaxAvailableTorchLevel error:nil];
```